# Align cursor to placeholder starting position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML and CSS code and the output.
When I click the input boxes I want my cursor to be exactly just on the left of the placeholder text. But when I click the input the box the cursor shows up at the very start of the the input box.
How can i align the cursor to the placeholder starting character on focus.
Thanks

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <title>AUMC-Student Portal</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css2/paper.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="css2/myCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="Login-Form-Container">
        <form class="Inner-Portion">
            <div>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
            </div>
            <br>

            <div>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
            </div>
            <br>

            <select class="form-control controls">
                <option selected>Laptop</option>
                <option value="">Mouse</option>
                <option value="">Keyboard</option>
                <option value="">Monitor</option>
                <option value="">Hello World</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Forgot</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
            <form/>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color: #293037;
    background-size: 1500px;
}

.Login-Form-Container {

    background-color: dodgerblue;
    width: 400pt;
    height: 310pt;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.Inner-Portion  {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    width: 400pt;
    height: 300pt;
    padding-top: 57pt;

}


.controls , .Inner-Portion div{
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 300px;
}


.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    padding: 55px;
}


.Inner-Portion div{
    border: solid 1px #DDDDDD;
}

.btn-default , .btn-primary {
    width: 150px;
}
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

Comment: Did you try `input.formcontrol{ padding-left:55px }`

Comment: @Sharlike I copy pasted your code at the end of my CSS file but had no effect. what is formcontrol in your code? is this the name of my class. but isn't my class name is form-control

Comment: yes it should be `input.form-control`. Anyways the point is you can set the padding left of the input which should achieve what you wanted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `text-indent` property.

```
input.form-control {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  text-indent: 30px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wns9vrje/)**

Or just set some `padding-left` for it.

```
input.form-control {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gpco6k01/)**

Comment: Thanks it worked, I see what happening here. You are creating a logical bounding box around the input field and just padding the text inside it. Am I right ? If so then if we only need a logical container around the input field then wouldn't putting the input field inside a div and and text-aligning the div work ? or am I looking at **box-sizing** property from  a wrong angle ? I tried doing this but output ain't the same look here https://jsfiddle.net/wns9vrje/3/

Comment: @Ahmed.J I would do it like what did above, so it's easier when you do some highlighting on `:focus` like that screenshot to change the color of the bottom border.

Answer (score 1):

You may add:

```
input.form-control {
    width: 100%;
   padding-left: 55px;
}
```

and remove .form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder.

The snippet:

```css
body {
    background-color: #293037;
    background-size: 1500px;
}

.Login-Form-Container {

    background-color: dodgerblue;
    width: 400pt;
    height: 310pt;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.Inner-Portion  {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    width: 400pt;
    height: 300pt;
    padding-top: 57pt;

}


.controls , .Inner-Portion div{
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 300px;
}


input.form-control {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 55px;
}

.Inner-Portion div{
    border: solid 1px #DDDDDD;
}

.btn-default , .btn-primary {
    width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Login-Form-Container">
    <form class="Inner-Portion">
        <div>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
        </div>
        <br>

        <div>
            <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
        </div>
        <br>

        <select class="form-control controls">
            <option selected>Laptop</option>
            <option value="">Mouse</option>
            <option value="">Keyboard</option>
            <option value="">Monitor</option>
            <option value="">Hello World</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Forgot</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work. I also ran your code snippet here and see for yourself that its still at the start of the input box.

Comment: I see and I'm using Chrome just to be precise. I got my solution from @Pangloss and it worked even on online editors without the styles.css I have on my drive. I wan't to know that why your code didn't do the trick ?

Answer (score 0):

This Code is enough.

```css
input {
   padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should make the padding to target the input and not the placeholder.

try something like this

```
 .form-signin input[type="email"], .form-signin input[type="password"]{

padding: 14px 16px !important;
margin: auto;
font-size: 17px;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Don't apply styles to the placeholder rather make it global to the input the placeholder will apply automatically

```
.form-control{padding:14px 16px;}
```